# how to change the font-face, color,size, ... using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a textarea, now want to provide the user with facility to change the font size,style etc. when i click on a button it should pop up the font dialog box.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form name="abc">
    <textarea name="text">loaded text here</textarea>
    <input type="button" onClick=""> chnage font
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i found thid code in http://www.smokyhosts.com/forums/showthread.php?t=740   by Lixas but it changes the textbox height and width when i change the text size

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, td, tg, input, select {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body onload="initPosition(document.forms[0].txtLayoutViewer)">
<form>
Change Font Size: 
<select onchange="this.form.txtLayoutViewer.style.fontSize = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; initPosition(this.form.txtLayoutViewer);">
<option value="10">10px</option>
<option value="12">12px</option>
<option value="14">14px</option>
<option value="16">16px</option>
<option value="18">18px</option>
<option value="20">20px</option>
<option value="24">24px</option>
<option value="36">36px</option>
</select>


<textarea name="txtLayoutViewer" rows="15" cols="75" wrap="off">Any text u want to see how it changes.</textarea>
</form></body></html>
```

Thanx to Christian textarea doesnt change now...using similar method is it possible to change the text font style (like bold, italic, regular, bold italic) and font face (times new roman , lucida handwriting) ????

thanx in advance

-subanki

Comment: have you tied anything already?

Comment: You may prefer using TinyMCE http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/ instead of re-implementing the wheel.

Comment: For what purpose? Is it just so that the user can select font while inputting, or do you plan to show the text for other users using the specified font? You can change the font for the whole textarea, but not for part of the text in it.

Comment: i want the users to be able to change the font size or make it bold, so that they can see the text clearly. especially old people find it difficult reading small text ... specially my teacher.....

Comment: i want the effect to take place in the entire text box and not just any part of text

Comment: is your question: how can i change style in javascript? or how can i load font-list in javascript? if former is pretttty straight forward, bing or google, the latter is, which font-list are you trying to load? selected fonts? or user's local fonts? what font dialog box are you referring to? the browser's built in dialog?

Comment: well i want the text box to behave exactly like a notepad .... i want to pop up the font dialog box just like the notepad.....and all files are local ...srry if this ddint answer ur queestion ....i guess i am super dumb coder.

Comment: **"Ctrl and +"** ?? *"..to change the font size, so that they can see the text clearly. especially old people...*

Comment: no ctrl and + dosnt work in textarea

Comment: i understand, the font dialog is a "windows-shell" dialog, you can't pop it up on browser, and even if you can, it wont change more than what a normal "ctrl+plus" does, both are user-level controls, meaning the user using the browser can control, not script inside browser... never the less, there have been a lot of javascript plugins to "increase and decrease size", do search "font size control javascript plugin"

Comment: thnks for the info, i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent the size beeing changed from the second example you need to set width and height instead of rows and cols.

```
<textarea name="txtLayoutViewer" style="width:500px;height:300px"
                      wrap="off">
  Any text u want to see how it changes.
</textarea>
```

using proper css would make it a bit cleaner.